# How to input ,(comma) and .(dot) into the TextBox at the same time in c#

Tags: c#, number-formatting

I wanna know how to input `,` and `.` into the TextBox at the same time

ex)

```
1,234.22,
12,554.00,
555,448,999.513
```

thank you very much

Comment: what will be your input? What is the condition to put comma and dot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use String.Format to do that, example:

```
// Output will be 555,448,999.513
string s = string.Format(new CultureInfo("en-US"), "{0:n3}", 555448999.513);
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way of String.Format to show , and . without CultureInfo

```
decimal v = 123018401398.313m;
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0:0,000.00}", v));
// Output is 123,018,401,398.31
```

Note that you need to specify the decimal count. This example only shows 2.